# Actions Builder webhookResponse Unexpected internal error at List Response

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

I tried to add a List Response from my webhook and always receiving an error such as:

```
Unexpected internal error id=c57c97b2-0b6f-492b-88a3-3867cf2e7203
```

(The id changes each time.)

After comparing the expected JSON webhookResponse from the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-selection#ListSamples) with the generated Response from the Actions SDK I found a difference at the `typeOverrides` object:
JSON from Docs

```
"typeOverrides": [
  {
    "name": "prompt_option",
    "synonym": {
      "entries": []
    },
    "typeOverrideMode": "TYPE_REPLACE"
  }
]
```

Generated JSON Response from Actions SDK

```
"typeOverrides": [
  {
    "name": "prompt_option",
    "synonym": {
      "entries": []
    },
    "mode": "TYPE_REPLACE"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an error in the example documentation, but the [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/reference/rest/v1/TopLevel/fulfill#typeoverride) say that it should be `mode`. I've tested it both ways, and that isn't causing the error.

The likely problem is that if you're replying with a List, you *must* do two things:

1. You need a Slot in the Scene that will accept the Type that you specify in the `typeOverride.name`. (And remember - you're updating the *Type*, not the name of the Slot.)
2. In the prompt for this slot, you must call the webhook that generates the list. (It has to be that slots prompt. You can't request it in On Enter, for example.)

Comment: Thanks! My mistake was that I set `typeOverride.name` to the _name of the slot_ and not the _name of the slot type_.

Comment: Ooo! Easy to overlook and good catch! Glad you found the problem.